# This button is not closing the alert

Tags: bootstrap-5

This bootstrap alert button is not closing the alert. please help.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include these in your head tag?

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me...

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those
      fields below.
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close"
      ></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```